# "Find Usage" feature stopped working in MPLAB X

Tags: search, find, mplab

All of a sudden the "Find Usage" feature in MPLAB X stopped working for me.  This is strange for several reasons:

1. It worked on the project I'm working on until my computer restarted (only event I can recall that may have cause a change)
2. It works in some other projects (but not all), and I can't figure out why it doesn't work in the project that I want.

The project was originally an MPLAB 8 project that was converted to MPLAB X, and like I said, that feature worked and I can't think of any environment changes that potentially caused it to stop working (other than a computer restart).

Any idea where to look, what options to change, or any other suggestions to get that feature back? I find it very helpful, so I'd like to get it back somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

- Close MPLAB X.
- Make sure it is completely finished (check by using task manager).
- Go to `%localappdata%\mplab_ide\Cache\dev\v3.20` (or the respective version).

  For example this path might be:

  ```
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\mplab_ide\Cache\dev\v3.20
  ```
- Delete the `var` folder (make a backup or just do a rename if you are unsure about the consequences).
- Restart MPLAB X.

Comment: To confirm that this worked for me using version 5.45 of MPLAB-X.  I renamed the directory out of an excess of caution.

Comment: @everybody:  Just to confirm that it also worked for me, Mplab v5.45. Great suggestion/solution user7009351:  easy, fast, efficacious. Would give you 1000 points!
(and much better than long complex advises found on Microchip forum...)